# Inequality of bounded linear operators on Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

> Let $T$ and $S$ [be bounded linear operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) on a Hilbert space
>   $H$. Verify that: $||TS||\leq ||T||\cdot ||S||$.

The definition of the operator's norm is $||T||=\sup\{||Tv||_H: ||v||_H=1\}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is one of the most trivial properties of bounded linear operators in a normed space - in fact, it's true in many other norms than the one you presented.  You should just think about it for a minute; the proof is a one-liner (often the knowledge that the proof is trivial is enough to help spur you along to the answer).

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any $x\in H$, $\|Sx\|\leq\|S\|\|x\|$ and similarly $\|Ty\|\leq\|T\|\|y\|$ for any $y\in H$.  Thus we have, for any $v$ with $\|v\|=1$,
$$
\|TSv\|\leq\|T\|\|Sv\|\leq\|T\|\|S\|\|v\|=\|T\|\|S\|
$$